# In sydney does setting [weak] in front of an object make a penalty?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In delphi sydney, does setting [weak] in front of an object (not an interface) make a penalty ?
Exemple :

```
  TMyObject = class(Tobject)
  Private
    [weak] FOwner: TMyObject;
    ....
  end;
```

I ask because I know that internally [weak] references are stored in a list and thus it's have some drawbacks (regarding speed). As now with Sydney ARC is gone there is no need anymore to put [weak] in front of an object (as far as I know), but as I want to keep my code compatible with Rio and less I ask if I can safely leave the [weak] reference without suffering of useless performance lost (in sydney)

> there is a teeny-weeny problem with the [weak] attribute. It denotes a
> zeroing weak reference that will be zeroed (niled) when the object it
> points to is no longer valid. In order to do that, the compiler has to
> track such objects at runtime and that introduces some overhead. If
> you are tracking many such references, that can introduce a
> significant performance loss.

Comment: It does not do anything at all.

Comment: @StefanGlienke any source to confirm this behavior? I did some test and yes look true but prefer to be 100% sure

Comment: You don't trust me as ultimate source of truth on this? Pff ;) Well, Rio has this page: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Automatic_Reference_Counting_in_Delphi_Mobile_Compilers#Weak_References  - Sydney documentation does not have it anymore. `[Weak]` never did anything when `WEAKINSTREF` was not defined - fwiw the page http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/de/Bedingte_Compilierung_(Delphi) is not correct - as `AUTOREFCOUNT` and `WEAKINSTREF` should not be defined on any platform anymore.

Comment: @StefanGlienke ahah yes I trust you, but you are ...well you are human :)

Comment: Typically, statements made by @StefanGlienke are more accurate than statements found on the docwiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[weak]` attribute for **object references** was only implemented on ARC compilers. On classic, non-ARC compilers `[weak]` attribute did nothing and had no penalty when used on object references.

Since 10.4 Sydney no longer has ARC compilers, `[weak]` attribute is no longer needed, but it can be used for maintaining backward compatibility. It will have no impact on code that is compiled with non-ARC compilers.

That `[weak]` has no impact on non-ARC compilers can be easily inspected through CPU view.

```
var
  Obj: TObject;
  [weak] WObj: TObject;
begin
  Obj := TObject.Create;
  WObj := Obj;

  Obj.Free;
end;
```

On Android ARC compiler 10.3 assigning `Obj` to weak `WObj` will call `_InstWeakCopy` procedure to keep track of weak reference:

[image: CPU view - ARC compiler]

Same code when compiled with 10.4 Android compiler no longer has call to `_InstWeakCopy`

[image: CPU view - non ARC compiler]:

---

Note: This answer strictly covers behavior of `[weak]` attribute when used on object references. Used on interface references `[weak]` works the same as before, since it was introduced in non-ARC compilers in 10.1 Berlin.

Comment: Of course, `[weak]` still has an effect on interface references. (I think some readers of this A might not see that if they read it out of context.)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand That is why I put __object references__ in bold, right on the top.